# Issue by attache activejdbc to my spring-boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activejdbc

I will attache activejdbc to my spring boot project, and this is part of my pom.xml file:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.javalite</groupId>
            <artifactId>db-migrator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${activejdbc.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <configFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/database.properties</configFile>
                <environments>${environments}</environments>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

But I got the following exception by executing the project.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Drive
```

Comment: add a full stack trace

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Drive
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
 at org.javalite.activejdbc.DB.open(DB.java:106) ~[activejdbc-2.0.jar:na]
 at org.javalite.activejdbc.DB.open(DB.java:89) ~[activejd

Comment: Even If I do Class.forName("org.postgresql.Drive") in the main class, I got the same issue. 
But the are parts of application which are working through the spring with that driver.

Comment: Your stack trace is not full. Also add it to the question, not comment

Comment: stack overflow is not allowed me to add full stack, says too much code.

Comment: Use other tools, lol. If you want help, your question must be researched